# Match columns to a list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
id          sub_id            others
NaN           10                xxx
10            11                xxx
10            13                xxx
10            15                xxx
11            12                xxx
11            16                xxx
13            14                xxx
15            17                xxx
12            20                xxx
16            55                xxx
16            85                xxx
14            19                xxx
14            43                xxx
17            87                xxx
17            91                xxx
```

Say, for instance id==10 is the boss in this dataframe. 
I have a list of levels : levels = [a,b,c,d] . In my list of levels , a denotes the boss and b denotes the level that is managed by the boss and c is the level managed by b and so on..

What I want to do is I want to see which id manages the sub_ids and based on that create a new column which says which level that sub_id corresponds to.

I want my final dataframe to be like the following:

```
id          sub_id            others      level
NaN           10                xxx         a
10            11                xxx         b
10            13                xxx         b
10            15                xxx         b
11            12                xxx         c
11            16                xxx         c
13            14                xxx         c
15            17                xxx         c
12            20                xxx         d
16            55                xxx         d
16            85                xxx         d
14            19                xxx         d
14            43                xxx         d
17            87                xxx         d
17            91                xxx         d
```

I am currently doing the following:

```
pointer_subid = []
loop_subid = []



data['level'] = np.nan
boss = data[data.id.isnull()]
data['level'][(data['id'].isnull())] = 'a'
pointer_subid.append([boss['sub_id'])

levels = ['b', 'c', 'd']
k=0
while k < len(levels):
    for i in range(0, len(pointer_subid)):
        for j in range(0,len(data)): 
            data['level'][(data['id'][j] == i)] = levels[k]
            loop_subid.append(data['sub_id'][j])
    del pointer_subid
    pointer_subid = list(loop_subid)
    del loop_subid
    loop_subid = []
    k = k+1
```

I am not sure if the above piece of code would work. It's been running for hours together now and I can't check if it's giving me the desired result or not either. Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
data['level'] = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(data['id'])), index=data.index)
levels = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d']

def findLevel(sub_id, cnt):
    idVal = data.loc[data['sub_id'] == sub_id]['id'].as_matrix()[0]
    if idVal == '-1': # Replaced the nan as -1 and -1 is a character here
        return cnt
    cnt += 1
    return findLevel(idVal, cnt)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    lvl = levels[findLevel(row['sub_id'], 0)]
    data.loc[index, 'level'] = lvl
```